# Sitecore Marketing Automation Service is failing many times

Tags: xconnect

Sitecore `Marketing Automation Service` is failing many times and a lot of `certificates` are getting generated. If we move this certificate and in `IIS` if we select another certificate and then again click correct certificate then this service will start. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to follow blog if this can help you, do it for Marketing automation service - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2022/02/23/failed-to-start-service-sitecore-xconnect-indexworker/

Answer (score 0):

To know the exact error,

- Open Command Prompt in `Admin` mode
- cd to Automation Engine path: `\sc9.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine`
- Run `maengine.exe` to manually execute the Automation Engine service

There can be multiple reasons why the marketing automation service is not running. Most of them can be resolved by:

- Set `AllowInvalidClientCertificates` to true in `\sc9.xconnect\App_Config\AppSettings.config`
- Comment out the next line with the key `validateCertificateThumbprint`